# Selecting specific tds in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to check checkboxes of the table if the rows contain specific value.

Below is my table

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #999999" id="tableControlFailures">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkCF">
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                C1
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999"
                id="tdCFReason">
                <input type="text" id="txtCFReason" style="width: 90%" disabled="disabled">
            </td>
            <td id="CFId" style="display: none">
                22
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkCF">
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                C2
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999"
                id="tdCFReason">
                <input type="text" id="txtCFReason" style="width: 90%" disabled="disabled">
            </td>
            <td id="CFId" style="display: none">
                23
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkCF">
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999">
                c
            </td>
            <td style="border-width: thin; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999"
                id="tdCFReason">
                <input type="text" id="txtCFReason" style="width: 90%" disabled="disabled">
            </td>
            <td id="CFId" style="display: none">
                9
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to check the rows where hidden column CFId contains 23 & 9.

Please suggestion a solution.

Comment: Please format your HTML code properly.

Comment: Do you know HTML at all? you have multiples `id`'s that have the same value! Go Back to tutorials and learn HTML again!

Answer (score 1):

A very important thing, as others also mentioned:

**An ID can only be used ONCE in a HTML document.** In your markup you're using IDs multiple times, which is simply not valid and will break both CSS and Javascript functionalities. If you want to assign some elements into the same logical group, use `class` instead. My solution works after changing those IDs into classes (as demonstrated in the jsFiddle).

```
$('#tableControlFailures tr').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('td.CFId:contains(23), td.CFId:contains(9)').length > 0;
}).find('input.chkCF').attr('checked', true);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rXheV/)

1. It gets all the rows in the table
2. Filters them with a filter function, only those will stay that have a `td.CFId` inside that contains either 23 or 9
3. In the remaining set of rows, find the checkboxes and check them

**Note:** My solution is written for jQuery 1.5.2. In 1.6, you should use `.prop('checked', true)` instead of `.attr('checked', true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rework little on the mark-up. You are repeating the id id="CFId" for table cell instead try class="CFId". JQuery offers solutions to read such elements using the CSS rules. So you should be able to read table cells with class CFId class using "td.CFId" css rule.

Then iterate it and check values. to reach to the row you can try ele.parentNode to do the CSS modifications to change the color and background based on the values.

```
//to change the color based on some value
if($(cell).innerHTML === '23') {
    $(cell).parentNode.style.color = 'red'
}
```

Unless you just don't want to stick the JQuery this solution should work for you with JQuery API and simple JavaScript.

Comment: `$(cell)` does not have properties like `innerHTML` or `parentNode`.

Comment: i just keep it like algorithm. So by $(cell) i intended to specify the cell element.

Comment: I get that it's just an algorithm description. But with `$(cell)` you clearly specify a jQuery object, I just said we should make things more complicated and ambiguous for a clear beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#tableControlFailures").find("td:contains('22'), td:contains('23')").parent("tr").find("#chkCF").prop("checked", true);
```

Example at [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sQpvV/1/)

However, as others have said, you should change your td to have unique ids and use the class to group elements. My solution will still work after you set unique ids

Comment: If it works and if you don't mind, could you mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$("table").find("td:contains('23'),td:contains('9')").find(":checkbox").attr("checked",true);'
```

Comment: please read jQuery 1.6+ news, never ever use `attr` again, use `prop`! :)

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for posting answer. I tried to run your solution at http://jsfiddle.net/VktaR/1/, but it is not working.

Comment: Won't work, because it will attempt to find the checkboxes in the hidden `td` containing the numbers. And they are not there.

Comment: @balexandre Yes, but 1.6.1 fixed this and now we can use either for certain attributes.

Comment: NO, you can't use `either`, you should use `prop()` **ALWAYS**! read more about it!